# Can $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ with non-empty set of limit points, be a finite set?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was wondering if it is possible to say that given $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that the set of limit points is not empty, $A$ can be a finite set?

I was thinking about it as consequence of Weierstrass theorem (if A is infinite and bounded,then it has at least one limit point), but is it also true the inverse? Am I on the right track?

Thanks

Comment: A finite set has no limit points.

Comment: A limit point, $p$. is one such that every open neighborhood contains a point of the set not equal to $p$.  Choose such a point and find a neighborhood small enough to no longer contain that point.  That neighborhood must contain another point of the set.

Comment: "A finite set has no limit points"  but isn't the OP asking why not?

Comment: I am actually asking, if a set has no limit points, is it finite?

Comment: "if a set has no limit points, is it finite" What? Of course not.  Consider the integers.

Comment: Oh, that's true

Comment: Besides, your question *specifically* does state "Can a set with an non-empty set of limit points be finite".  "having a non-empty set of limit points" = "having at least one limit point".  So that *was* your question even if that wasn't your intent.  Logic comment say "no".... I usually assume when someone asks a question they don't just what the answer but an understanding of why. ... Then again I also usually assume they know what question they asked.... So.... What's your question?

Comment: Well, yes. I was trying to get an explanation for that, that's why I asked

Comment: If $A$ has no limit points and $A$ is bounded, then $A$ is finite, otherwise B-W would be false.

Comment: "If A has no limit points and A is bounded, then A is finite, otherwise B-W would be false."  But what does that have to do with sets that *do* have limit points?  Can they be finite?  And why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're on the wrong track.

Consider the definition of limit point: $x$ is a limit point of the set $A$ if (and only if) every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains a point of $A$ different from $x$.

Instead of generic neighborhoods you can use intervals of the form $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$. Now what can we do? Start from $\delta_0=1$ and select $a_0\in (x-\delta_0,x+\delta_0)\cap A$, $a_0\ne x$.

Next we choose $\delta_1=|x-a_0|/2$ and we select
$$
a_1\in(x-\delta_1,x+\delta_1)\cap A,\quad a_1\ne x
$$
For obvious reasons, $a_1\ne a_0$. This starts a recursion! Suppose you have found distinct points $a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}$ in $A$ all different from $x$; then fix
$$
\delta_n=\frac{1}{2}\min\{|x-a_0|,|x-a_1|,\dots,|x-a_{n-1}|\}
$$
and you can choose
$$
a_n\in (x-\delta_n,x+\delta_n)\cap A,\quad a_n\ne x
$$
so that $a_n$ is different from the previous ones. Since you can go on forever, you conclude that $A$ is infinite.

Note that the same proof can be adapted to any metric space, where Weierstrass theorem doesn't necessarily hold.